# Can't read `yaml` config properly using `Config.fromConfig`

Tags: java, kubernetes

I'm encountering an issue when trying to read a `k8s.config.yaml` file in my Java application using the Kubernetes API client. The code snippet I'm using is as follows:

```yaml
private ApiClient readConfigFromFile(String filePath) throws IOException {
    String yamlContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));
    return Config.fromConfig(yamlContent);
}
```

However, the `Config.fromConfig` method is throwing an exception, even though I can confirm that the YAML content is loaded correctly as a string. I've set a debug point and checked that the content of `.yaml` is loaded properly.

What my config looks like:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: xxxxx
    server: https://api.mydomain.com.bd:port
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-super
  name: kubernetes-super@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-super@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-super
  user:
    client-certificate-data: xxxxx
    client-key-data: xxxxx
```

Complete stacktrace:

```
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:213)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:152)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
    at io.kubernetes.client.util.Config.fromConfig(Config.java:80)
    at com.mua.testservice.k8s.K8sService.readConfigFromFile(K8sService.java:39)
    at com.mua.testservice.k8s.K8sService.readPods(K8sService.java:47)
    at com.mua.testservice.k8s.K8sService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f7a2349d.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at com.mua.testservice.k8s.K8sService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$305cd403.readPods(<generated>)
    at com.mua.testCliRun.run(CliRun.java:25)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:768)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
    at com.mua.testK8sExpApplication.main(K8sExpApplication.java:10)
```

And this is library I am using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.kubernetes</groupId>
    <artifactId>client-java</artifactId>
    <version>15.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**How can I resolve this? And load this yaml config properly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the code](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/1c7c6d3a8cc22a4a9c6e07878472af5ac4fdc583/util/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/util/Config.java#L79), if you call `Config.fromConfig` with a `String` parameter, it expects a filename.

Instead of reading the YAML into a `String` and then trying to parse the string, you could just pass the filename directly to `Config.fromConfig`:

```java
api = Config.fromConfig(filePath);
```

If you really want to read the configuration from a `String`, there is a version of the function that [accepts a Reader](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/1c7c6d3a8cc22a4a9c6e07878472af5ac4fdc583/util/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/util/Config.java#L93), so we can create a [`StringReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html):

```java
String filePath = "kubeconfig";

try {
    String yamlContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));
    Reader reader = new StringReader(yamlContent);
    api = Config.fromConfig(reader);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Oops:" + e);
}
```